# Erro na classificação de textos com arvore

Tags: python

Estou tentando classificar, mas está dando o erro. Segue o código, depois o erro.

```
#coding=UTF-8  

import io  
import os  
import pandas as pd 
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer  
from sklearn import tree  

pasta="c:/users/usuario/dados"  
os.chdir(pasta)  

def main():  
    df=pd.read_csv('twits_classificados.csv', encoding='ISO-8859-1', sep=";")  
    exemploArvore(df)  

def exemploArvore(df):  
    textos=df['texto'].values  
    sentimento=df['sentimento'].values  

    #a linha abaixo traz a frequencia de palavras
    vectorizer = CountVectorizer(analyzer="word")  

    freqWords = vectorizer.fit_transform(textos)


    modelo = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()

    modelo.fit(freqWords, sentimento)

    texto=["estou com medo da violência"]
    fwTexto=vectorizer.fit_transform(texto)

    print(modelo.predict(fwTexto))


main()
```

O erro:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\USUARIO\workspacePython\testes\arvore.py", line 39, in <module>
>     main()
>   File "C:\Users\USUARIO\workspacePython\testes\arvore.py", line 14, in main
>     exemploArvore(df)
>   File "C:\Users\USUARIO\workspacePython\testes\arvore.py", line 36, in exemploArvore
>     print(modelo.predict(fwTexto))
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\tree.py",
> line 404, in predict
>     X = self._validate_X_predict(X, check_input)
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\tree.py",
> line 376, in _validate_X_predict
>     % (self.n_features_, n_features))
> ValueError: Number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features is 2765 and input n_features is 5
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Você só deve chamar o método `fit_transform` durante o treino, no teste você deve chamar apenas o método `transform` do seu vectorizer.

No seu teste, troque a linha:

```
fwTexto = vectorizer.fit_transform(texto)
```

Por

```
fwTexto = vectorizer.transform(texto)
```